# CloudKit public database writeable without iCloud account

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Is there any way to make the CloudKit public database writeable for users without an iCloud account?

Comment: What have you tried ? Did you do any investigations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple documentation you must be logged in iCloud to write data in publica database

> For a running CloudKit app, a container’s **public database is always
>   readable**, even when the user is not signed in to their iCloud
>   account on the device. **Saving records to the public database** and
>   accessing the private database **requires that the user be signed in**

Read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/DesigningforCloudKit/DesigningforCloudKit.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it server side using the API key and you can call your own API when users are not logged in.